# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in http request

Tags: javascript, cors, httprequest

I am running a server on my localhost with an HTML5 application.
I would like to send an http-request to a second server "130.100.100.100:50000".

I have the following JavaScript code running on localhost where I am sending http requests to the second server.

```
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {}
    };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://130.100.100.100:50000/company.html/query?a0=" + a0, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        xmlhttp.send();
```

The second server is receiving my queries but I don't get any answer for my request. I think the problem is that the Same Origin Policy is violated. I tried to use the CORS standard to set

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

But the GET requests I am sending still doesn't contain "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the header. If I send the request manually with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" everything is working proper. Do I have a mistake in my JavaScript code? I would like to avoid using jQuery.

Comment: You have to allow that from the server you are requesting too.

Comment: So if I don't have access to that server I can't send requests to this server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/42744707#42744707

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow cross origin on server. Follow https://ma.ttias.be/set-access-control-allow-origin-cors-headers-apache-vhost-htaccess/

Comment: The server I am sending requests to has to allow cross origin right?

Answer (score 0):

You need a page used as a proxy. This page will send a GET request to the target page and display the response. Make sure that relative paths at `img`, `a`, `script` and `link` are converted to full paths. If you do this, the CORS problem will be fixed.